# System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly "AppName" after update xamarin forms

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, file-not-found

I can't rebuild the project and I'm getting this exception after updating to latest Xamarin Forms 3.4.0.1008975  , if I downgrade it to 3.1.0.583944 or lower the exception will gone and I can build successfully.

I've tried to update VS and clean - close - reopen but the problem still there , I also tried to move the project to C:/ but no luck .

```
Error       The "ResolveLibraryProjectImports" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'SouqAlData, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
File name: 'SouqAlData.dll'
   at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference reference, ReaderParameters parameters)
   at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(String fullName)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveLibraryProjectImports.Extract(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res, ICollection`1 jars, ICollection`1 resolvedResourceDirectories, ICollection`1 resolvedAssetDirectories, ICollection`1 resolvedEnvironments)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveLibraryProjectImports.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() SouqAlData.Android
```

[image]

Comment: In addition to regular cleaning try deleting the obj and bin folders from all project folders and then try again.

Comment: Can you add the exception in text format, that makes it easier to copy/paste for referencing and searching?

Comment: Yes i deleted the obj-bin , same result .

Comment: I edited the post ..

Comment: which VS version do you use? Update to 15.9.2 and look if you can build it now.

Comment: I'm using 15.9.1 ... this issue started from yesterday and i just noticed the new update .

Comment: I updated it , clean - rebuild - deleted obj,bin.. but still same error .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding of the situation tells me that you do not have the latest version of Xamarin which comes along with [`Visual Studio 15.9.xx`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2018/11/19/visual-studio-2017-version-15-9-now-available/).

And hence when you update your Xamarin Forms package to the latest version of that is available it sees a discrepancy in between the versions and hence might be throwing this. One more reason could be that when you update your Xamarin Forms package, somehow the path for your `SouqAlData.dll` is lost by VS and hence you get this error. What I would suggest you do in case two is that you provide the proper path for your .dll again to VS and see if that helps you build the project.

**You can give the path as follows:**

- Remove the existing reference to the .dll
- In your project go to **References>Add Reference>Browse** then give it the .dll path from your solution directory.

**Update:**

From recent Xamarin forms update code behind doesn't support Task return type as signatures for event handlers.

So Replacing the Task with Void return type did the trick. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52895166/7462031)

Comment: Well i can't reference it because it doesn't exist , like i said i can't build the project ... when i downgrade to a lower version i can build the project and the directory that contain .dll is there ... but when i update the packages and hit rebuild the netstandard2.0 directory that contain SouqAlData.dll doesn't exist and i think that because the project hasn't successfully been built in the first place  .

Comment: Is `SouqAlData` a project in your solution or an external dll?

Comment: Did you try updating visual studio to the latest version?

Comment: so this issue only happens with the latest version of Xamarin forms dll am i right?

Comment: Well it just worked after i saw this answer (From recent Xamarin forms update code behind dont support Task return type as signatures for event handlers.) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52893416/xamarin-skiasharp-signature-return-type-of-eventhandler-doesnt-match-the-eve

Comment: So converting it to void did the trick ha nice, You want me to update it in my answer and you will mark it right?

Comment: Yeah .. you can do that .

Comment: Done Take and revert in case i have not added something!

Answer (score -1):

This error happens when you have another error in the solution in your case in xaml file check for you xaml code for a mismatch code or events. In my case i found "-->" in the xaml file and it was the problem.